# property model of object mongoose is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm using Mongoosejs, with MongoDB and Node.js.
I followed some online tutorials and created myself a test app as below, but keep getting the error message "propert model of object mongoose is not a function.

I dont understand what this means and why its erroring since i followed the online tutorials near enough the same.

Here is my code

```
// MongoDB test app. Getting to know MongoDB via MongooseJS

var mongoose = require ('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema 
var Storydb = new Schema ({

title: String,
body: String,
date: Date

});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

//setup model and pass it schema
mongoose.model = ('Storydb',Storydb);

var StoryModel = mongoose.model ('Storydb');

var story = new StoryModel();

//Insert Data
story.title = 'The Man in the green shirt';
story.body = 'once upon a time, way back';
story.date = Date.now();

//save
story.save(function(err){

if (err) {throw err; }
console.log('saved story');
mongoose.disconnect();

});`
```

I've already tested my MongoDB connection. No issues there, and i am able to insert and retrieve data via the Mongo CLI.
I have also tested my Node.js configuration with basic Hello World examples, and no issues with configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
//setup model and pass it schema
mongoose.model = ('Storydb',Storydb);
```

you should do:

```
//setup model and pass it schema
mongoose.model('Storydb',Storydb);
```

Comment: Oh i see. We are calling a function to which we are passing parameters. Silly me. Let me try that and report back to you. Thanks alot ;-)